# pgfkeys: How to group multiple styles together

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

For now I put all my `tikz/pgf` keys/styles in the global scope. However, I'd like now to do it more properly not to pollute the global scope with useless styles, my goal being to group styles together among a common name like:

```
styleA/.style={
  amazing/.style={fill=red},
},
styleB/.style={
  amazing/.style={fill=orange},
}
```

and then I would simply load a given style using `\node[styleA,amazing]` (or using `every node` to load style automatically).

The above code works greatly... except if I add arguments to my styles. Then I need to use `##1` instead of `#1` to target the first argument (otherwise I guess it takes the argument of the parent "styleA" object):

```
  mystyleA/.style={
    amazingCode/.style={fill=##1},
    amazingCode/.default=red,
  }
```

However, it is a bit error prone... and in some libraries like `\tikzcd` they don't have this issue. Instead, they do some sort of `styleA/.cd`, but for some reasons they manage to fallback on tikz if no key is found in `styleA`... How can they do that?

## Edit

After I found a first part of the answer, I still have one question: I can do `\node[/mystyleDcd/.cd,amazingCode]`, but I can't move `/mystyleDcd` using `every node/.prefix style{...}`. Any idea why?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\pgfqkeys{/mystyleDcd}{
  .search also={/tikz}, % fallback to tikz, equivalent to /mystyleDcd/.search also={/tikz}
  default props/.style={
    shape=circle
  },
  amazingCode/.style={fill=#1}, % equivalent to /mystyleDcd/amazingCode/...
  amazingCode/.default=purple,
}

Works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[/mystyleDcd/.cd,amazingCode,text=green] {search also};
\end{tikzpicture}

Fails:
% \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.prefix style={/mystyleDcd/.cd}]
%   \node[amazingCode,text=green] {search also};
% \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My advice: use TikZ only, you do not need to remember any special command of `tikz-cd`. So relaxing!

Comment: Well I do use some feature of `tikz-cd`. Now my goal is also to understand how it works ^^

Comment: If you are ok with usages like `mystyleDcd=styleA|styleB|...`, then key handler `/.is choice` would reduce the need for doubling escape char(s) by one level.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found the answer (well not entirely, see my edit). There is a key `.search also` (usage like `.search also={/tikz}`) in pgfkeys which allows you to define fallback "folders". This is itself based on `.unknown`, and `tikz-cd` uses directly `.unknown`... I guess they have a good reason (maybe because they allow strange keys like `rrrd`), but in most cases `.search also` is enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  mystyleA/.style={
    amazing/.style={fill=red},
    amazingCode/.style={fill=##1},
    amazingCode/.default=red,
  },
  mystyleB/.style={
    amazing/.style={fill=orange}
  },
  /mystyleC/amazing/.style={
    /tikz/fill=orange
  },
}

%% could also have been defined using:
%% /mystyleDcd/.cd, % Go to /mystyleDcd "folder"
%% .search also={/tikz}, % equivalent to /mystyleDcd/.search also={/tikz}. Fallback to tikz,
%% amazingCode/.style={fill=#1}, % equivalent to /mystyleDcd/amazingCode/...
%% amazingCode/.default=purple,

\pgfqkeys{/mystyleDcd}{
  .search also={/tikz}, % fallback to tikz, equivalent to /mystyleDcd/.search also={/tikz}
  amazingCode/.style={fill=#1}, % equivalent to /mystyleDcd/amazingCode/...
  amazingCode/.default=purple,
}


\section{Version with nested styles}
I can use tikz keys, redefine style locally...
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyleA]
  \node[amazing]{Using nested mystyleA};
  \node[amazing,/tikz/text=green] at (3,0){/tikz/text};
  \node[mystyleB,amazing,text=green] at (5,0){text};
\end{tikzpicture}

With arguments:
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyleA]
  \node[mystyleA,amazingCode] at (1,0){text};
  \node[mystyleA,amazingCode=yellow] at (5,0){text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Version with cd}
I can't use tikz keys (see comments)
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node[/mystyleC/.cd,amazing] (a) {Forcing cd in node};
  \node[right=of a,/mystyleDcd/.cd,amazingCode,text=pink] {search also};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second and remaining question:

> After I found a first part of the answer, I still have one question: I can do `\node[/mystyleDcd/.cd,amazingCode]`, but I can't move `/mystyleDcd` using `every node/.prefix style{...}`. Any idea why?

**Firstly some `pgfkeys` staff**

In `pgfkeys`, by using handler `/mystyleDcd/.cd`, you are setting `/mystyleDcd` as the new *default path*.

Initially, the default path is `/`, hence `\pgfkeys{key1}` is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{/key1}`. There's another macro `\pgfqkeys{<dpath>}{<keyvals>}` which is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{<dpath>/.cd, <keyvals>}`.

**Then we meet `tikz`**

`\tikzset` is defined as `\def\tikzset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz}}` so `\tikz{<keyvals>}` is equivalent to `\tikz{/tikz/.cd, <keyvals>}`.

Here's the key point: in `node` internals ([1](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/b561e46fbc36215fe8b8459bc2234d1b0670f654/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L3798) and [2](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/b561e46fbc36215fe8b8459bc2234d1b0670f654/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L3816)), for input `\node[<options>]`, `every node/.try` and `<options>` are executed by *separate* `\tikzset`s. Therefore node options are always parsed in a scope (not the `{scope}` env) in which the default path is `/tikz`.